# Undefined option name javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code. But the alert does not show the name of the option, instead it shows "undefined". For value, it shows the correct content.

```
<select id="test" name="select_decision" onchange="javascript:
var activeText = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
var activeOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex].name;
alert(activeOption);
">
```

An example of one option is:

```
<option value="test" name="test_name">Test</option>
```

Been looking on google for an answer but cannot find one!

Comment: [html option elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) do not have a `name` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`option` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element) don't have a `name` attribute, so there's no reflected property for it, so `optionElement.name` is `undefined`.

While you *could* get the value of that attribute via `optionElement.getAttribute("name")`, in general if you want to add a custom attribute to an element, you should use the [`data-*` prefix](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

Comment: @coffeeak: `label` is for the text of the option. It's invalid for an `option` element to both have a `label` attribute *and* text content. What's your purpose/goal for this `name` thing?

Comment: @JanDvorak: That would give them `test` rather than `test_name`. It's not clear to me what this `name` thing is for, but they're already getting the value, so I figure there's something separate they're looking to do...

Answer (score -1):

Try to use htmlElement.getAttribute(attrName). So, in your case try to use

```
var activeOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('name');
```

instead of your

```
var activeOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex].name;
```